# Android Home option in menu not working in KitKat

Tags: android, menu

I have an app having a home button in menu. This is working fine on all Android versions except the KitKat.

My client has reported that it is not working on Kitkat, I am using the following code for menu.

```
android:parentActivityName="net.cabin.leaders.CabinActivity"
android:label="@string/flight_info">
 <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="net.cabin.leaders.CabinActivity" />
```

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUp(true);
```

will do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in Android with Home button (sadly, I don't remember the issue number now). The trick is to do it like this:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

It will work on all versions